# Netsuite Saved Search a list of ID's by invoice No

Tags: list, netsuite, invoices

I have a request to extract specific Invoices, over the course of an year. For target invoices i have the following information to use: Invoice Number, Invoice date, Order Ref, Value and currency. I tried extracting few months at a time, but it's too much data.

Is there a way to filter on about 200 unique Invoice No in Netsuite?

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: You can do this with Suitescript. Do you know or have anyone that knows how to run Suitescript?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I will do some research, to see if it's to complicated. I'm a programmer so hopefully i'll be able to learn SuiteScript

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a Formula(Numeric) filter in your criteria like this:

```
Filter: Formula (Numeric)
Description: is greater than 0
Formula: INSTR(',SLS00000101,SLS00000102,SLS00000103,SLS00000104,SLS00000105,', ',' || {tranid} || ',')
```

Note that the initial string is a comma separated list of document numbers that **begins and ends with a comma**.

I'm not sure if there is an upper limit on formula size, but I've used this pattern to find a large number of transactions when I know the document numbers or internal IDs.